# Turborepo - node modules not being tree shaken even though not being used

Tags: reactjs, turborepo

Trying to wrap my head around Turborepo so I might be doing something wrong here.
Here is my current turborepo setup (you can see the full code in [this repo](https://github.com/uriklar/turborepo-treeshaking-repro))

I have two components in my ui package:

`Button` - uses `styled-components` and `framer-motion`
`Loader` - uses neither..

*Button.tsx*

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export const Button = () => {
  return (
    <ButtonContainer
      initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.5 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
    >
      Boop
    </ButtonContainer>
  );
};

const ButtonContainer = styled(motion.button)``;
```

*Loader.tsx*

```
import * as React from "react";

export const Loader = () => {
  return <div>MyLoader</div>;
};
```

and this is the package.json for the ui library:

```
{
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-custom": "workspace:*",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "styled-components": ">=5.3.3",
    "tsconfig": "workspace:*",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "framer-motion": "^2.9.4"
  }
}
```

My `docs` app only imports the `Loader` component (that uses no libraries).
and the `web` app only imports the `Button` component (that uses both styled and framer)

Is it correct to expect the docs app not to include these libraries in it's bundle? Should I define the dependencies in a different way? (Let's assume framer motion will only be used inside the ui library, so I wouldn't want it as a peer dependency)

When I build the apps, their bundle is exactly the same size (IE, their both getting both 3rd party libraries in the bundle?)

Build output:

```
docs:build: Page                                       Size     First Load JS
docs:build: ┌ ○ /                                      44.3 kB         115 kB
docs:build: └ ○ /404                                   192 B          71.3 kB
docs:build: + First Load JS shared by all              71.2 kB
docs:build:   ├ chunks/framework-18dbf282fc9f86dd.js   42 kB
docs:build:   ├ chunks/main-7adb95b49d154e8e.js        26.9 kB
docs:build:   ├ chunks/pages/_app-5e74c22d5551a606.js  1.37 kB
docs:build:   └ chunks/webpack-49b6f2937c9ce9f4.js     838 B
docs:build:
docs:build: ○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
docs:build:
web:build: Page                                       Size     First Load JS
web:build: ┌ ○ /                                      44.3 kB         115 kB
web:build: └ ○ /404                                   192 B          71.3 kB
web:build: + First Load JS shared by all              71.2 kB
web:build:   ├ chunks/framework-18dbf282fc9f86dd.js   42 kB
web:build:   ├ chunks/main-7adb95b49d154e8e.js        26.9 kB
web:build:   ├ chunks/pages/_app-5e74c22d5551a606.js  1.37 kB
web:build:   └ chunks/webpack-49b6f2937c9ce9f4.js     838 B
```

**PS** - I do see that tree shaking works for the components (IE - The `Loader` component doesn't appear in the `web` app's bundle, and the `Button` component doesn't appear in the `docs` app bundle). But the lib's don't seem to be tree shaking.

Thanks!

Comment: you got any solution?